# What type of baked goods require challah to be taken?

Tags: halacha, separating-challah

I've only seen people taking challah from the dough if they are baking bread or matzah. I noticed [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22893/5275) that addresses fried dough (e.g. some types of donuts.)

Would one need to take challah if he is making wafers, cookies or cakes?

Comment: In what way is the answer there insufficient?

Comment: It seems to address only fried foods. Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: Do you consider pasta to be a baked good?

Comment: Ah yes, that's a good point. It's boiled, which I think you've addressed in that question. I don't think you've addressed cakes and wafers, though.

Answer (score 1):

[Star K](https://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/1197/when-you-need-to-knead-a-guide-to-hafrashas-challah/) says:

> When kneading dough for baking pas haba’ah b’kisnin (e.g. cake and
>   cookies), for boiling (e.g. noodles), or for frying, one is mafrish
>   Challah if 2.6 lbs. (82/3 cups) of flour are used. A bracha is not
>   recited even if more than 5 lbs. of flour are used.

He bases his opinion on Aruch Hashulchan Y.D. 329

I should mention that the term "pas haba’ah b’kisnin" is quite ambiguous and includes what are commonly called "mezonot rolls". This dough usually contains a large volume of fruit juice, and, thus, may not be considered "hamotzi" bread according to some opinions. The article addresses taking challah from such dough mixtures.

Comment: I cook in a yeshiva and I was told by the menahel to take challah when I make cake. Without a bracha.

Comment: @mroll it is a batter or a dough?

Comment: @DoubleAA they are batters. Don't know his logic.

Comment: @mroll From my understanding of Star-K's article, it seems that the bracha, at least, is specific to using the dough as bread which is specifically "hamotzi" bread. I have to look up the definition of "batter". Pancake batter usually has a large amount of (butter)milk which may place it outside the dough category, anyway, similar to the fruit juice amount in many mezonot rolls. Cake batter may be a different story as it seems to be similar to challah dough in terms of dough quantity, when used industrially (bakery, eg.)